# Control flow in T-SQL SP using IF..ELSE IF - are there other ways?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to branch my T-SQL stored procedure (MS SQL 2008) control flow to a number of directions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [fooBar]
   @inputParam INT
AS
BEGIN
  IF @inputParam = 1
  BEGIN
    ...
  END
  ELSE IF @inputParam = 3
  BEGIN
    ...
  END
  ELSE IF @inputParam = 3
  BEGIN
    ...
  END
END
```

Is there any other ways? For example, in `C#` I shoud use `switch-case` block.

Comment: The BEGIN/END isn't necessary unless you are doing multiple things within that portion of the decision logic.

Comment: @rexem: Yea, I know. I deliberately wrote this because every block contains a lot of code

Comment: @rexem, anytime I omitted the begin end, I regretted it later on in maintenance when someone forgot to add them when they added a second step to the branch of the IF. I always use them now.

Comment: @HLGEM: Good point, I haven't had that pleasure yet :)

Comment: Just another reason why I find PLSQL to be a better approach - packages and ";" delimited instructions.

Comment: @rexem: SQL Server _does_ support ; as a delimiter, but it's optional. Except for the `WITH` construct for some reason. But, yeah, as an Oracle developer working on SQL Server, I do miss my PL/SQL packages :-)

Comment: Stored procs, to perform well, should do just one task, and minimize this type of conditional logic in T-SQL. A better design is to make several procs that each does one task, and decide in your application which to call. This is a fundamental difference from full-on programming languages. Cached plans are a problem with if/then, though SQL 2008 made some progress w/statement-level recompilation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

IF...ELSE... is pretty much what we've got in T-SQL. There is nothing like structured programming's CASE statement. If you have an extended set of ...ELSE IF...s to deal with, be sure to include BEGIN...END for each block to keep things clear, and always remember, consistent indentation is your friend!

Comment: I always write my ifs and begin and end before writing the code that will go between the begin and end, saves a whole lot of debugging later to put in the begin ends before any code that goes in between.

Comment: there exists case statements in T-SQL

Comment: T-SQL case statements are, how to say it, used as "clauses", parts of other statments--most commonly, SELECT statements. They cannot be used to control programmatic flow as they do in assorted .NET languages.

Comment: In our copy-paste driven world, it would be nice if this answer contained an actual example ;)

Comment: True, but, the original question contains an example of the `if-else if` with `begin/end` structure, and another example would have been redundant.

Answer (score 22):

Also you can try to formulate your answer in the form of a `SELECT CASE` Statement. You can then later create simple if then's that use your results if needed as you have narrowed down the possibilities.

```
SELECT @Result =   
CASE @inputParam   
WHEN 1 THEN 1   
WHEN 2 THEN 2   
WHEN 3 THEN 1   
ELSE 4   
END  

IF @Result = 1   
BEGIN  
...  
END  

IF @Result = 2   
BEGIN   
....  
END  

IF @Result = 4   
BEGIN   
//Error handling code   
END
```

Comment: this would be the exact job for [GOTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 12):

No, but you should be careful when using IF...ELSE...END IF in stored procs.  If your code blocks are radically different, you may suffer from poor performance because the procedure plan will need to be re-cached each time.  If it's a high-performance system, you may want to compile separate stored procs for each code block, and have your application decide which proc to call at the appropriate time.

Comment: This is very true. But if the branching can only occur within the procedure (as opposed to your application calling one of several procedures), you're still stuck with a series of IF statements.

Comment: My proc name [execOperation] have been calling from ASP.NET FormView with parameter from dropdown list which contains a list of possible operation types.. So I have no possibility to have a number of separate procs, unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

The [Transact-SQL control-of-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow?view=sql-server-ver15) language keywords are:

> [`BEGIN`*...*`END`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`BREAK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/break-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`CONTINUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/continue-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`GOTO` *label*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`IF`*...*`ELSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`RETURN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`TRY`*...*`CATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`WAITFOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>   [`WHILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

Nope IF is the way to go, what is the problem you have with using it?

BTW your example won't ever get to the third block of code as it and the second block are exactly alike.

Answer (score -1):

```
CASE expression
      WHEN value1 THEN result1
      WHEN value2 THEN result2
      ...
      WHEN valueN THEN resultN

      [
        ELSE elseResult
      ]
END
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20210728081626/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102704-1.shtml For more information.

Comment: This is only applicable for queries. I need to write anything inside block, i.e. many lines of code with different queries and other SP's calls

Comment: In T-SQL CASe is an **EXPRESSION** not a controll branch. Very different beasts.

Comment: This is out of the SELECT statement context.