# Case statement to execute code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am familiar using Case in a Select statement, etc.

But I am unsure how to use it to execute code, like using it instead of an If statement.

Does anyone know if it's possible?  I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
CASE @Variable
  WHEN 0 THEN 
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1
      ...
      BREAK;
  WHEN 1 THEN
      SELECT * FROM TABLE2
      ...
      BREAK;
END
```

In other words, I should get this functionality:

```
if(@Variable=1) SELECT * FROM TABLE1
if(@Variable=2) SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

But using a case statement for the argument.

This is a sample of code, so please do not take it literally. The objective is find out if you can use CASE statements in the same manner as a `IF` `THEN` statement.  Like using `switch` in `c#`

Comment: You can't use a CASE in this way.

Comment: You cant but can be done with dynamic sql...

Comment: This answer from a related question demonstrates a novel way of using CASE: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16341062/152891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `CASE` **statements** do not exist. The SQL Standard only speaks of [`CASE` *expressions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622/sql-case-statement-syntax), of which you're aware. This has already been mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562160/control-flow-in-t-sql-sp-using-if-else-if-are-there-other-ways).

Keep in mind that the [`IF...ELSE` statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587(v=sql.110).aspx) are vendor-specific, and are not part of the standard. But they're basically all we have in this regard.

Comment: I had a feeling you couldn't use it like this. I was just asking to make sure, since all other Ms technologies I've used do have a Case/Switch statement for arguments.  But I guess your answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: @ControlFreak: Yes, unfortunately, T-SQL is often lacking in the "programmer-niceties" department when it comes to programmatic-type things, as opposed to relational-type things.